# How do I use Sequelize to connect to Heroku Postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js

this is my configuration:

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

export const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL as string,
    {
        dialect: 'postgres',
    }
)
```

error:

```
ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "186.194.175.39", user "xuavcbfkstvqrm", database "d3t76co8ov8vqm", SSL off
    at Client._connectionCallback (d:\Projetos-VSCODE\Crud-tsnode\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\connection-manager.js:189:24)
    at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (d:\Projetos-VSCODE\Crud-tsnode\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:305:19)
    at Client._handleErrorMessage (d:\Projetos-VSCODE\Crud-tsnode\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:325:19)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Connection.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at d:\Projetos-VSCODE\Crud-tsnode\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:114:12
    at Parser.parse (d:\Projetos-VSCODE\Crud-tsnode\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:104:9)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (d:\Projetos-VSCODE\Crud-tsnode\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\index.ts:7:48)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12) {
  parent: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "186.194.175.39", user "xuavcbfkstvqrm", database "d3t76co8ov8vqm", SSL off
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (d:\Projetos-VSCODE\Crud-tsnode\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:369:69)
      at Parser.handlePacket (d:\Projetos-VSCODE\Crud-tsnode\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:188:21)
      at Parser.parse (d:\Projetos-VSCODE\Crud-tsnode\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:103:30)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (d:\Projetos-VSCODE\Crud-tsnode\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\index.ts:7:48)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
      at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23) {
    length: 168,
    severity: 'FATAL',
    code: '28000',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'auth.c',
    line: '496',
    routine: 'ClientAuthentication'
  },
  original: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "186.194.175.39", user "xuavcbfkstvqrm", database "d3t76co8ov8vqm", SSL off
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (d:\Projetos-VSCODE\Crud-tsnode\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:369:69)
      at Parser.handlePacket (d:\Projetos-VSCODE\Crud-tsnode\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:188:21)
      at Parser.parse (d:\Projetos-VSCODE\Crud-tsnode\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:103:30)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (d:\Projetos-VSCODE\Crud-tsnode\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\index.ts:7:48)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
      at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23) {
    length: 168,
    severity: 'FATAL',
    code: '28000',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'auth.c',
    line: '496',
    routine: 'ClientAuthentication'
  }
}
```

What is missing in my code to connect correctly?, doing this test and being able to connect to the postgresql database on heroku, I will upload the application and I believe that the CRUD that needs to access the route and add the user will work, but I have to do it this connection to the heroku database, but I'm not getting it

Comment: I suppose it's just for security's sake not to let anyone from inet to connect to this DB outside. Find out how to allow your IP in Heroku DB settings